# Amount of elementary events in comparison to all events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

So I've got this question here, that i think i know the answer but i don't know how to prove it. It goes like this:

> Can a number of all elementary events be greater than the number of all events? Is it possible that a) number of elementary events is finite but number of all events is infinite? b)number of all events is finite but number of elementary events is infinite?

I really think that number of elementary events can be greater than the number of events but I'm not really sure what are the examples of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're asking this in a very basic probability theory context so I am giving a basic answer.

No, the number of elementary events cannot be greater.
Because to every elementary event $a$ ($a$ is member of $\Omega$)
corresponds the event $A = \{a\}$ (which is a subset of $\Omega$).

The answers to both a) and b) are NO.

a) NO because if number of elementary events is finite $N$, then the number of events is at most $2^N$
b) NO because of the first note above